# Deploy ruleapp from one server to another with ant

Tags: jrules, ibm-odm

I am using odm 8.0.1.I need to make an ant script where I can deploy a ruleapp on existing server to a different server.Like I have my ruleapp on E1 server and i need to deploy that ruleapp from E1 to E2 with help of ant automation.

Please help .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This should not be an issue.
Here is the sample from IBM Site. Have you tried it.? for more info 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSQP76_8.6.0/com.ibm.odm.dserver.rules.ref.res/ant_tasks/con_ant_res_deploy.html

Here is the path to ant tasks.
IBM Operational Decision Manager 8.6.0>Operational Decision Manager V8.6>Decision Server Rules>Reference>Rule Execution Server reference>Ant tasks>Ant tasks for RuleApp management>res-deploy

Change host name to whatever you want.

```
<res-deploy hostname="localhost" 
            portnumber="9080" 
            userid="res" 
            password="mypassword" 
            file="myruleapp.jar"/>
```

Comment: Can you help me with "How to fetch a xom from res".Not res-fetch-all as it will fetch all esources.I need to fetch a selected xom from res to my local. Is it possible?

Comment: No, As per the IBM docs, I don't see any way to achieve this.